# Use sed to edit a line in a file with spaces in the name

Tags: sed

I am looping through folders, opening a file within the folder with the same name, and doing some manipulation.

I'm using sed to manipulate a line:

```
sed "1s/Log R Ratio/$SAMPLE.LRR/" $FILE
```

where $FILE is a file with 1+ spaces in the name.  Example:

```
NAT062813_Batch A_1_TR27GD1_CytoScanHD_NL_092913/NAT062813_Batch A_1_TR27GD1_CytoScanHD_NL_092913.txt
```

Is there a way (without going through and renaming things) to use sed with these files?
I tried putting quotes around $FILE, but that just printed it out.

Comment: What kind of quotes did you try? `"$FILE"` or `'$FILE'`?

Comment: You also want to watch it if your `$SAMPLE` variable contains any `/` characters (or `&` or `\`).  And, you might want to try embedding the whole `sed` command in an `-exec` operator to the `find` command rather than looping by hand.

Comment: I only tried double quotes.  I'll try singles.  @Wildcard I'm new to writing shell scripts.  Can you give an example of this?  I was under the impression that a for loop is better (speedier) than find.

Comment: There's no problem with using a `for` loop to iterate through *files*, actually.  The big anti-pattern is using a `for` loop to iterate through *lines* of a file; see the question I linked to from my answer about shell loops for processing text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rereading your question, I think you are just missing the `-i` option to `sed`.  That is the option that makes `sed` edit the file in place rather than printing the results to standard output.

Note that it is a very good idea to *test* your `sed` command *before* using the `-i` switch, as there is no "undo" command if you get it wrong.

So, for example, if you run `sed 's/old/new/' myfile`, you will see the contents of `myfile` printed out on your terminal with the first instance of `old` on each line replaced with `new`.  If you run `sed -i 's/old/new/' myfile`, you won't see anything printed out—`myfile` will be (irrevocably) edited in place.

You can also use, for example, `-i.bak` instead of `-i`, which will cause the original file to be saved as `myfile.bak` and the edited file to appear as `myfile`.  (You can define whatever extension you want instead of `.bak` and it doesn't need to start with a dot, but `.bak` is conventional to use for this purpose.)

Quotes around your space-containing filename is a separate issue and the answer to that is simple—use double quotes to get variable expansion without word splitting.  So if you have a variable `filenamevariable="My file name which contains spaces"`, you need to refer to it like so: `sed 's/old/new/' "$filenamevariable"`

Some other recommended reading:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)
- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, missing the -i option for sed was the issue.  And thanks for the links.  I'm still not sure I understand how to do other methods to avoid loops, but I'll look into it.  I do mostly R programming, which has built in methods to avoid loops...I'll have to figure this out for shell scripting.

Comment: Again, nothing wrong with using a `for` loop to iterate through files, i.e. one time through the `for` loop to handle one file.  Just avoid "one time through a `for` loop to handle one *line* of a file" and you'll be fine.  ;)